# How to find a specific character in a string and put it at the end of the string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have this string:

```
'Is?"they'
```

I want to find the question mark (?) in the string, and put it at the end of the string. The output should look like this:

```
'Is"they?'
```

I am using the following regular expression in python 2.7. I don't know why my regex is not working.

```
import re
regs = re.sub('(\w*)(\?)(\w*)', '\\1\\3\\2', 'Is?"they')
print regs
Is?"they # this is the output of my regex.
```

Comment: The `they` really changed into `thay`!? :o

Comment: typing error it is they.

Comment: Why are you using a regular expression?

Comment: that seems easier to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), `"` is not captured by `\w`.  Hence, it would probably be best to just use a `.`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("(.*)(\?)(.*)", r'\1\3\2', 'Is?"they')
'Is"they?'
>>>
```

`.` captures anything/everything in Regex (except newlines).

Also, you'll notice that I used a [raw-string](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) for the second argument of `re.sub`.  Doing so is cleaner than having all those backslashes.

Comment: works too:                                                          regs = re.sub('(\w*)(\?)([\W\w]*)', '\\1\\3\\2', 'Is?"they')

Comment: @Coddy - Yes, that works too.  Note however that this `[\W\w]*` is identical to this `.*`.

Answer (score 3):

Your regex doesn't match because `"` is not in the `\w` character class. You would need to change it to something like:

```
regs = re.sub('(\w*)(\?)([^"\w]*)', '\\1\\3\\2', 'Is?"they')
```